# Matching up how parameters are displayed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm working on a report that has two parameters.  One is a parameter which automatically gets populated with the user ID number (let's call this Parameter1) by default when it is first run.  The second parameter (let's say Parameter2) is a list of names.  Does anyone know how to make Parameter2 automatically change based on the value of Parameter1 when the report runs the first time and then for Parameter 1 to change if the user selects a different value for Parameter2.

In other words, when someone opens the report, they get a default value of their own user ID number in Parameter1 with Parameter2 just showing "". I'd like Parameter2 to show that person's name.  Then if they change Parameter2 to another name, I want Parameter1 to change to that name's user ID number.[image]

Comment: No, parameters can only cascade in one direction.

Comment: Do you really need both parameters? Could you remove parameter 1 and then set the default for parameter 2 to be your user id?

Comment: Thank you both, that helps to know they can only go one direction, and the idea to only have one parameter makes a lot of sense.